# OCaml: Upon encountering an exception, the for cycle should just ignore it and continue without tossing me out

Tags: for-loop, exception, matrix, ocaml

So i have this code:

```
let matrix = [|
  [| true; true; true |];
  [| false; false; false |];
  [| false; true; true |];
  [| true; false; false |]
|];;

for i = 0 to 10 do
  for j = 0 to 10 do
    try 
      if matrix.(i).(j) = true then 
        print_string "works"
    with
    | Invalid_argument "Index out of bounds" -> ();
  done;
done;
```

I want the exception handler to just continue the loop without printing works, instead it tosses me out and still gives me an exception. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Please note that the semicolons in your code are entirely unnecessary.

Comment: The semicolons separating the elements of the array are quite necessary though.

Comment: Goes to show how I don't even think of them as semicolons. They're just array or list "separators" in my mind.

Comment: @Chris True, because i just picked up OCaml cause of a course after studying Java i had to quickly learn how the semantics work. I had to do quite a bit of code debugging and was messing around with ; and brackets. In the end the brackets were the problem (not in this case), but i had left them accidentally for most of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I compile this I get:

```
Warning 52: Code should not depend on the actual values of
this constructor's arguments. They are only for information
and may change in future versions. (See manual section 9.5)
```

Well, you ignored this, so when I run it I get:

```
worksworksworksException: Invalid_argument "index out of bounds".
```

`"Index out of bounds"` is not the same as `"index out of bounds"`. You are catching the wrong exceptions.

Comment: I changed the capital letter and now it works. Thanks. By the way, is the warning a serious issue? Is there a better way to handle exceptions?

Comment: You don't need to specify the string at all, unless you're trying to handle _different_ `Invalid_argument` exceptions. You can just use `with Invalid_argument _ -> ()`.

Answer (score 1):

Goswin is correct about the case mismatch in matching the exception. You also have unnecessary semicolons in your code as you are not chaining multiple expressions together.

```
for i = 0 to 10 do
  for j = 0 to 10 do
    try 
      if matrix.(i).(j) = true then 
        print_string "works"
    with
    | Invalid_argument _ -> ()
  done
done
```

Also note that in OCaml 4.02 and later, we can handle exceptions directly in a `match`, so this code could be expressed as:

```
for i = 0 to 10 do
  for j = 0 to 10 do
    match matrix.(i).(j) with 
    | true -> print_string "works"
    | false | exception Invalid_argument _ -> ()
  done
done
```

If you wish to avoid the exception handling altogether, you could quite simply bounds check.

```
let height = Array.length matrix in
for i = 0 to (min 10 (height - 1)) do
  let width = Array.length matrix.(i) in
  for j = 0 to (min 10 (width - 1)) do
    if matrix.(i).(j) then 
      print_string "works" 
  done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

In general,  `Invalid_argument _` exceptions should not be catch nor matched.
Those exceptions are meant as programming errors that should be avoided before they happen. In this specific case, this means checking that the indices are within the bound of the matrix before using them.

For instance:

```
for i = 0 to 10 do
  for j = 0 to 10 do
    if i < Array.length matrix && i >= 0
    && j < Array.length matrix.(i) && j >= 0
    && a.(i).(j)
    then print_string "works"
  done
done
```

It is also possible to define a matrix access operator that returns an option type in order to factorize the bound checking outside of the loop:

```ml
let (.?()) a (i,j) =
  if i < Array.length a && i >= 0
  && j < Array.length a.(i) && j >=0
  then
    Some (Array.unsafe_get (Array.unsafe_get a i) j)
  else None

for i = 0 to 10 do
  for j = 0 to 10 do
    match matrix.?(i,j) with
    | None | Some false -> ()
    | Some true -> print_string "work"
  done
done
```

Comment: In this situation, as specified by the OP, I believe you'd want something more like: `match matrix.?(i, j) with Some true -> print_string "work" | _ -> ()` as nothing is printed if the value in the matrix is `false`.

Comment: Indeed, I have edited my code to match the initial question. Thanks!